# When is auth.authResponseChange, auth.logout etc. fired? Safari and Firefox behave different

Tags: javascript, facebook

I don't get when exactally the different Events for FB.Event.subscribe are fired...

In Safari auth.logout and oauth.authResponseChange are fired on EVERY page reload, not only when something changes.

In Firefox auth.logout and oauth.authResponseChange are only fired ONCE...

Can someone explain this behaviour? And what is the best way to detect, if a user has logged out or has e.g. removed the permission for my app? I thought auth.logout is called then automatically.